# Finding the number of characters in a text string up to a certain character

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have some notes in my XML document. Each note follows this rule:

```
NOTE1
NOTE1<div>NOTE2</div>
<div>NOTE2</div>
```

In my XML I have:

```
<MeetingWorkBook>
   <Labels>
      <Note>Note</Note>
   </Labels>
   <Meeting>
      <Note>Note1</Note>
   </Meeting>
   <Meeting>
      <Note>Note1&lt;div&gt;Note2&lt;/div&gt;</Note>
   </Meeting>
   <Meeting>
      <Note>&lt;div&gt;Note2&lt;/div&gt;</Note>
   </Meeting>
</MeetingWorkBook>
```

In the XSL file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
        doctype-public="//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-off.css"/>
                <title>Title</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
                    <table>
                        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(Note) != ''">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="borderDotMeetingNotes" colspan="4">
                                    <xsl-if test="normalize-space(substring-before(Note, '&lt;div&gt;') != '')">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Note"/>:&#160;
                                    </xsl-if>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Note" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </table>            
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What am I trying to achieve? In the final output, if there is a NOTE1 then I want to display the "Note: " label prefix. That is all.

The third example fails because there is no NOTE1. This is harder to explain than it really is. :(

I have tried:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(Note) != ''">
    <tr>
        <td class="borderDotMeetingNotes" colspan="4">
           <xsl-if test="normalize-space(substring-before(Note, '&lt;div&gt;') != '')">
                <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Note"/>:&#160;
           </xsl-if>
           <xsl:value-of select="Note" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:if>
```

But "Note:" still appears.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the expected output of the two given examples? -- Please don't post XSLT snippets taken out of their context - see: [mcve].

Comment: I have added a couple of examples. That help?

Comment: No, I am afraid I find it too confusing.

Comment: So did I! Getting used to the formatting. I have made another change, see if it is better.

Comment: There is no use saying things "in my XML" and "in my XSL". We need to be able to reproduce your issue, and for that you need to show a complete example. A complete and minimal example of your XSLT stylesheet and XML input, that is. It is hard to debug snippets of code that cannot be run. Please do read this help page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Thanks.

Comment: Your input XML does not match with your XSLT. The XSLT mentions `Note` elements. There are no `<Note>` elements in the XML you show. Same thing with `<Labels>`. Focus! We can't help you if your code samples are not coherent.

Comment: I understand all your comments. I have tried to improve the question. The XML sample is complete. Just working on the XSL.

Comment: I have updated the XSL example too. I don't know if I needed to add as much as I did.

Comment: If you want to check for the string `Note1` why don't you use `contains(Note, 'Note1')`?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Would this be a correct assessment of the problem: (a) you want to count the number of "real" notes (that is the substrings before, after or in-between the escaped `div`s), within each `Note` and (b) the required number cannot be derived from counting the number of the escaped `div`s.

Comment: That is just an example. Think of Note1 and Note2 as placeholders. The user will have actual text strings in there. The only rule is that is that the first placeholder is up to the div. So, if there is a div in the text string, and if there is actual a string from 0 up to that div then this will be the first note. We only want to show the "Note: " prefix if there is actually a first note. <scratches head>

Comment: Michael, kind of. I just want to take "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" and see if it has a "div" tag. If it does, want to extract the text up to that div. Eg: "aaaaa<div>bbbbb</div>" returns "aaaaa". So we *do* have a first note, so we *do* want to display the "Note: " label prefix. *But* if the text string was "<div>bbbbbb</div>" then the text before the div is empty, so there is *no* first note, so don't show the label. I think it has been made more complicated than it is.

Comment: I have formatted your question and removed from it a `</div>` element. Was it a typo?

Comment: Thanks Mathias. I had extracted it from a bigger script. I appreciate your help with that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly (which is not at all certain) you want to make your test:

```
<xsl:if test="substring-before(Note, '&lt;div&gt;')">
    <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Note"/>:&#160;
</xsl:if>
```

**Note**: you need to use `<xsl:if>`, not `<xsl-if>`.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention. Oops! I have done it like you showed and it is better. However, if the original text string has whitespace before the div it thinks it a note. This was why I was trying to trim the whitespace from whatever the substring was. So we have progress, thanks, but if it is " <div>Note2</div>" it would still show the "Label: " prefix and a empty note1. Make sense?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Just wrap the whole thing in normalize-space: `test="normalize-space(substring-before(Note, '&lt;div&gt;'))"`.

Comment: Thanks! That helped. I also provided a modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers already provided and subsequent comments.

It seems that using **normalize-space** still confused things and in the end I did this which appears to be fully operational:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(Note) != ''">
    <tr>
        <td class="borderDotMeetingNotes" colspan="4">
            <xsl:if test="normalize-space(substring-before(Note, '&lt;div')) or not(contains(Note, '&lt;div'))">
                <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Note"/>:&#160;
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="Note" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:if>
```

Note that in the end I also only searched for **<div** since the user would actually have a **class** associated with the div.

Comment: It did not seem to be so. When I just had "Note 1" as the string it was not showing the "Note: " label. That is why I added it as a specific test.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I had the polarity reversed. Withdrawn.